# WaitForSingleObject gives Invalid Handle

Tags: c++, asynchronous, waitforsingleobject

```
h=CreateFile("c:\\test.txt",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);

    OVERLAPPED ol2;
    memset(&ol2,0,sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    ol2.hEvent=CreateEvent(NULL,false,false,NULL);
    if(!ReadFile(h,iobuffer+pointsize,value,NULL,&ol2))
    printf("Last Error %u",GetLastError());
    if(WaitForSingleObject(&ol2.hEvent,INFINITE)!=0){
        printf("Last Error %u \n",GetLastError());

    }
```

WaitForsingleobject returns invalid handle, yet I do not see why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be written:

```
if(WaitForSingleObject(ol2.hEvent,INFINITE)!=0){
            printf("Last Error %u \n",GetLastError());
```

Note the removed & before ol2.hEvent

Comment: Indeed: `WaitForSingleObject` takes a `HANDLE`, not a `HANDLE[]` like `WaitForMultipleObjects`